# This copy and paste from another workbook macro should run, then change # that is part of the If statement so that it never runs again. Does nothing

Tags: excel, vba

I made a system for maple farmers that is very user friendly, but, even with detailed step by step instructions, no one has ever tried to do the annual files rollover and setup --  I just do it for them.  I know that it’s not responsible of me to leave it as is, so I am making it very easy for them to manage when I’m gone (or my mind goes south).   I have asked both Cornell and U Vt if I can bequeath the system to them, but their Agriculture folks are pretty scared of anything IT.  Anyway, I’m nearly done now, but need help to make the below code work.  It’s not opening the first file and I hope it’s something simple that you can see to fix it.  I will Call this code near the end of ThisWorkbook Open() code.  It copies the prior year’s list of Producers so that the farms don’t have to start from scratch.  It only runs at the first opening of the New Year file so that their New Year changes don’t get overwritten by last year’s list.

```vb
Sub CopyPasteProducerNames()

If Sheet2.Range("U1").Value = "File found" & Range("U5") = 1 Then
    
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("V6").Value
    Sheet2.Range("A7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range(V5).Value
    Sheet2.Range("A7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("U5") = 2
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

("V5") cell reads C:\Users\Michelle\Documents\Maple Inventory System\2025 Maple System Files\2025 SYRUP MANAGEMENT\2025 PURCHASED INVENTORY LOG.xlsm -- V6 is same but 2024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Always specify the worksheet when referencing a range to ensure the reliability of your code. `Range("U5")` is equivalent to `ActiveSheet.Range("U5")`. ActiveSheet is changed after opening a workbook.
- Using `And` in `If` clause instead of `&`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPasteProducerNames()
    Dim SrcSht As Worksheet, DesSht As Worksheet
    Dim SrcWb As Workbook, DesWb As Workbook
    If Sheet2.Range("U1").Value = "File found" And Sheet2.Range("U5") = 1 Then
        Set SrcWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Sheet2.Range("V6").Value)
        Set DesWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Sheet2.Range("V5").Value)
        If SrcWb is Nothing or DesWb is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set SrcSht = SrcWb.ActiveSheet ' modify as needed, eg. SrcWb.Sheets("Product")
        Set DesSht = DesWb.ActiveSheet
        With SrcSht.Range("A7", SrcSht.Range("A7").End(xlDown))
            DesSht.Range("A7").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
        Sheet2.Range("U5") = 2
        SrcWb.Close False
        DesWb.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! for your help, Taller.  Your code worked down to Sheet2.Range("U5") = 2, so I debugged it by removing that line and then it failed on the next line, et cetera.  Running the code also ceased calculation/macros for the Workbook.

Comment: `Range("U5") = 2` is in your code. Is the cell U2 on Sheet2? `SrcWb.Close False` just closes 2004 workbook. You can remove it you don't need to close it. What's the error? Please clarify the meaning of `ceased calculation/macros for the Workbook`.

Comment: It works great, Taller.  You couldn't know and I forgot that U2 is in a protected area of Sheet2, but remembered that as soon as I sent comment.  Added an unprotect bit, then re-protected when done and all ran great.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To have strong control of the Range parent workbook and worksheet you could use the With object … End With construct, as follows:

```
Option Explicit


Sub CopyPasteProducerNames()

    Dim sourceWb As Workbook, destinationWb As Workbook
    
    With Sheet2 ‘reference the currently active workbook sheet whose codename is ”Sheet2”
        If .Range("U1").Value = "File found" And .Range("U5").Value = 1 Then
            Set sourceWb = Workbooks.Open(.Range("V6").Value)
            Set destinationWb = Workbooks.Open(.Range("V5").Value)

            .Range("U5") = 2
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    With sourceWb ‘reference the source workbook
        With .ActiveSheet ‘reference the referenced workbook activesheet
            With .Range("A7", .Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp)) ‘ reference the referenced sheet range from cell A7 to the last not empty cell of column A
                destinationWb.ActiveSheet.Range("A7").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value ‘ copy referenced range values to destination workbook active sheet from cell A7
            End With
        End With
    
        .Close False ‘ close the referenced workbook
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  Taller's code worked perfectly once I remembered that U2 is in a protected area of the sheet.  Oops and thanks again for helping me and others.